# Calling a function from a function inside an imported file

Tags: python, function, import

I have a file, let's call it `One.py`:

```
from Two.py import example2

def example2():
   print "something!"
```

and another file named `Two.py`:

```
def example1():
   print "Other thing!"
   example2()
```

However, on the bottom line when I try to call `example2()` it doesn't recognize it. I would like to avoid simply importing `One.py` into `Two.py` because this would create an import loop.

Comment: btw your import is wrong, and why you redefined example2. Please clarify.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all. Shouldn't you be importing `example1` from `Two.py`? And note that you leave out the `.py` - `from Two import example1`. What are you actually trying to achieve?!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you import by simply naming the module, without the file ending:

```
from Two import example2
```

This should horribly fail, as there is no definition of `example2` in `Two.py`

A simple example to do what I guess you want looks like that:

`One.py`:

```
def function1():
    print 'I am function 1'
```

`Two.py`:

```
from One import function1
def function2():
    print 'I am function 2'
function1()
function2()
```

Comment: If you really need to use function 1 inside function two and then import function 2 into the One module, you might be better of defining both functions inside the same module.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments stated, your code doesn't make too much sense. Let's look at your `Two.py` file:

```
#Two.py
def example1():
print "Other thing!"
example2()
```

The file containts the definition for a function named `example1`, which prints a string. When executed, `example2()` will never get called because `example2()` was never declared anywhere. If you declare it locally, you will need to add a function in `Two.py` that defines it. For example, append the following lines of code to your `Two.py` file:

```
def example2():
    print "Example 2 was called"
```

Now, when you try to call the function, the compiler will know what you want it to do because you declared it locally. If, on the other hand, you did not declare the function in the same file but have defined it elsewhere, you can import the function from another file. Since `One.py` has a definition for `example2()`, you can import the module in your `Two.py` to gain access to it. Your final two files should look like this:

```
#Two.py
from One.py import example2  #instead of importing it from elsewhere, you can also define it in the actual file
def example1():
    print "Other thing!"     #notice the indentation that you left out
example1()
example2()

#One.py
def example2():
    print "something!"
```

This will execute without error.

To understand what went wrong with your implementation, consider the following line of code:

```
from Two.py import example2
```

The above states that there is some file called `Two.py` and that it contains a definition for a function called `example2`. But if you take a close look at your `Two.py` file, you can see that there was no `example2` to import. Thus, the compiler issues a warning telling you something is wrong.